# Is there a toggle for zoom/bigger text in OS X?

Tags: macos, accessibility, zoom

In Ubuntu there is a toggle "Bigger text" you can activate, that's really comfortable when you have a big screen.

In Windows there is a wonderful option that make everything bigger in proportion, the size you like, and you don't have to care about anything else.

I can't find anything in the System Preferences but is there anything on OS X? After all they're the one selling 27" iMac everyday...

If not, is there something third party you would suggest?

EDIT1: Changing resolution does not help at all. If you do it, you will notice that the words get all more checkered and that makes them even more unreadable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct equivalent in OS X - the closest is probably to simply decrease the resolution.

[TinkerTool](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5721/tinkertool) has options to change system and application font defaults, but doing so may cause application or OS crashes.

Comment: +1 for the tool I didn't know, that is something, but it is not exactly the solution. This is what i get in SysPref if I try to enlarge the fonts a little bit...  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78049918/Schermata%202013-07-09%20alle%2023.22.44.png

Comment: changing the resolution is not a solution. If you do it, you will notice that the words get all more checkered and that makes them even more unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-plus and Ctrl-minus works in some browsers to increase and decrease the shown size.

Universal Access has key combinations to zoom in and out in general (with or without mouse).  Look in System Preferences -> Accessability -> Zoom for those specific to your system.

[image]
(stolen from https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/90638/3157)